# Ubuntu 19.04, wireless mouse scroll wheel not functioning properly

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-gnome, 19.04, mouse-scroll, mouse-wheel

I have wireless mouse - **Logitech M560**

After upgrade to Ubuntu 19.04 scroll wheel stopped functioning properly.
It's very slow, if I turn off and on mouse, it starts functioning normally, but after some time gets slow again.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with ubuntu 19.10 and a Logitech mouse mx 25.

Comment: same issue with my mouse,  FENIFOX Wireless Keyboard and Mouse,2.4G USB Ergonomic Silent Full-Size Compact for PC Laptop Mac iMac Windows